# Парсинг XML в Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, синтаксический-анализ

Есть **`xml`** файл:

```
<result>
    <response>
        <code>200</code>
    </response>
    <tracks>
        <track id="XXXXXXXX">
            <code>402</code>
        </track>
    </tracks>
    <geo></geo>
</result>
```

---

Нужно получить переменную типа **`string`** в которой будет значение "*`тега`*"

```
result=>code=>tracks=>track id="XXXXXXXX"=>code
```

То есть, ***402***.

---

Сам смог только загрузить **`xml`**:

```
XDocument Info = XDocument.Load("http://xxx.xx/id=" + textBox1.Text);
```

Значение **`textBox`**'а в данном случае `XXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Статья на `CodeProject`, которую вам подкинули - не очень :)*

- Конкретно для вашего случая стоит активнее использовать [`Descendants`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants)
- Вот код `all-in-one` тестового кейса для вашей `xml'ки`, когда будете реализовывать что-либо подобное, то внимательно проверяйте возможность возврата пустой коллекции каким-либо из методов.
- То есть, если метод `Descendants()` допускает в качестве аргументов пустую коллекцию *(см. пятый `Assert.Equal` сверху),* то, когда вы начинаете работу с отдельными аргументами, получить `NullReferenceException` достаточно просто.

  ```
  [Fact]
  public void CanParseCustomXmlFile()
  {
      const string xmlString =
          @"<result> +
              <response>
                  <code>200</code>
              </response>
              <tracks>
                  <track id=""12345"">
                      <code>402</code>
                  </track>
              </tracks>
              <geo></geo>
          </result>";

      var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

      Assert.Equal(1, document.Descendants("result").Count());
      Assert.Equal(2, document.Descendants("code").Count());
      Assert.Equal(1, document.Descendants("track").Count());

      Assert.Equal(1, document.Descendants("track").Descendants("code").Count());
      Assert.Equal(0, document.Descendants("dwdwdq23423fxwdqwd")
                              .Descendants("code").Count());

      var trackNodes = document.Descendants("track");

      var trackNodesWithId = trackNodes.Where(
          trackNode => trackNode.Attribute("id") != null);

      var trackNode12345 = trackNodesWithId.Where(
          trackNode => trackNode.Attribute("id").Value == "12345");

      Assert.NotNull(trackNode12345);
      Assert.Equal(1, trackNode12345.Descendants("code").Count());
      Assert.Equal("402", trackNode12345.Descendants("code").First().Value);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**[Вот.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument)** Должно помочь!